# How to access JSON data outside of function?

Tags: javascript, json

How do I access "people" from readPeopleJSON function and "cars" from readCarsJSON function in the for loop at end of my code? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

People.json:

[{id: 1, name: "Tom", carid: 1},{id: 2, name: "Bob", carid: 1},{id: 3, name: "Sir Benjamin Rogan-Josh IV", carid: 2}];

cars.json

[{id: 1, name: "Ford Fiesta", color: "blue"},{id: 2, name: "Ferrari", color: "red"},{id: 3, name: "Rover 25", color: "Sunset Melting Yellow with hints of yellow"}];

```
//Get Peple from people.json
function readPeopleJSON(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readPeopleJSON("people.json", function(text){
    var people = JSON.parse(text);
});

//Get Cars from cars.json
function readCarsJSON(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readCarsJSON("cars.json", function(text){
    var cars = JSON.parse(text);
});

//List People and car deatils
const result = [];
for (const peop of people) {
  const car = cars.filter(d => d.id === peop.carid)[0];
  result.push({
    person_name: peop.name,
    name: car.name,
    color: car.color
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

---

This is the result i'm looking for.

Name: Tom

Car Name: Ford Fiesta

Color: blue

Comment: Declare `var cars, people` outside the functions. You should also go through basics about variables and scopes in JS

Comment: I got this error msg.
json.html:56 Uncaught TypeError: people is not iterable
    at json.html:56
(anonymous) @ json.html:56
VM921:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at json.html:33
    at XMLHttpRequest.rawFile.onreadystatechange (json.html:24)
(anonymous) @ json.html:33
rawFile.onreadystatechange @ json.html:24
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
readPeopleJSON @ json.html:27